# Mongoid - Replacing first element of an array in lookups/joins on belongs_to relations

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Let's assume this simple relation:

```
class Thing
  belongs_to :user # Not embedded!
end
```

And this simplified aggregation on `Thing` where we want to get the user object:

```
{ :$match => { ... } },
# Get user from belongs_to relation
{ :$lookup => {
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'user_id',
        foreignField: '_id',
        # Always has one element, because it's a belongs_to relation
        as: 'user'
      } },
```

In an aggregation there are two ways of replacing a field with the first element of an array.

1. With `addFields` and `arrayElemAt`:

```
  { :$addFields => { user: { :$arrayElemAt => ['$user', 0] } } }
```

2. With `unwind` (assuming one element in the array):

```
  { :$unwind => { path: '$user' } }
```

Question: I prefer the `unwind`, since it looks cleaner, but saw people using the first approach quite often. Is it faster or the "better practice"?

Comment: Unwind creates new documents which duplicates data. That slow down your query and also create memory issues. The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.

Comment: @ashok-patidar As stated above, the resulting array has always only one item, so an unwind won't create another row/item, but replaces the array with an object in the current item.

Comment: The first approach is better then unwind because it is ok in one to one relation but create a problem in one to many and other relations when data is more than expectation. Its style and approach of coding and also better practice. Sorry if I didn't help.